# How to delete series that meet multiple conditions at the same time in prometheus?

Tags: prometheus, promql

Following query works for all with `instances=127.0.0.1:9090`:

```bash
curl -X POST -g 'http://127.0.0.1:9090/api/v1/admin/tsdb/delete_series?match[]={instance="127.0.0.1:9090"}'
```

Following query works for all with `job=node`:

```bash
curl -X POST -g 'http://127.0.0.1:9090/api/v1/admin/tsdb/delete_series?&match[]={job="node"}'
```

If I just want to delete series with `instance=127.0.0.1:9090` and `job=node`, how can I query it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following query:

```
curl -X POST -g 'http://127.0.0.1:9090/api/v1/admin/tsdb/delete_series?match[]={instance="127.0.0.1:9090", job="node"}'
```